# How to supress displaying the plot in matplotlib, Seaborn and then displaying the ax object in which it has been stored

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, seaborn

I have created a function that creates an Empirical Cumulative Distribution Function using Seaborn and returns it as an ax object. However when I call the function the plot is displayed and I would like to suppress that.

Furthermore, I would like to know how to display the ax object returned by the function.

For a reproducible example:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

def ECDF(df, column, xlabel, ylabel, title, label, fig_size)


    x = df[column].sort_values() 


    y = np.arange(1, len(x) + 1)/len(x)

    f, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=fig_size)

    _ = sns.regplot(x, y, fit_reg = False, scatter_kws = {'s' : 1}, label = label, ax = ax)
    ax.set_xlabel(xlabel)
    ax.set_ylabel(ylabel)
    ax.set_title(title)
    ax.legend()

    return ax       


iris = sns.load_dataset("iris")
ax1 = ECDF(df = iris[iris['species'] == 'versicolor'], column = 'petal_length', \
            xlabel = 'Petal Length (cm)', \
     ylabel = 'Percent of Flowers with at most this Petal Length (cm) ', \
     title = 'Empirical Cumulative Distribution Function \n Petal Length (cm)', \
           label = 'versicolor', fig_size = (12,7))
```

When I run this command I get the following plot displayed automatically:

[image]

Furthermore, when I examine the object returned I get:

```
type(ax1)
matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot
```

How can I show the plot ax1?

Comment: Are you running matplotlib in *interactive* mode (see here https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/introductory/usage.html#interactive-example). You may try to add `plt.ioff()` before your code, then the display of the graph should be delayed until you call `plt.show()`

Comment: Thank you.  How about displaying the object ax1 that is returned from the function?  How can I display the plot encapsulated in it?